# My Android Program Fragment can't link to other activities, I don't know where is the problem

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a Home fragment for `MainActivity`. There are 21 buttons, each of them link to one activity. I used `OnClickListener` from the buttons. When I clicked them, I should have go to the activity. However when I pressed the buttons, they didn't link me to other activities. This is my code and I don't know why. Please help me.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private View view;
    private Button button_greetings, button_general_conversation, button_accommodation, button_celebration,
            button_city_and_prefecture, button_colors, button_country_and_region, button_dating,
            button_directions_and_places, button_drink, button_eating, button_emergency, button_family,
            button_feeling, button_numbers, button_shopping, button_sick, button_time_and_date,
            button_tongue_twisters, button_tourist_attractions, button_transportation;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        button_greetings = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_greetings);
        button_greetings.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_general_conversation = view.findViewById(R.id.button_general_conversation);
        button_general_conversation.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_accommodation = view.findViewById(R.id.button_accommodation);
        button_accommodation.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_celebration = view.findViewById(R.id.button_celebration);
        button_celebration.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_city_and_prefecture = view.findViewById(R.id.button_city_and_prefecture);
        button_city_and_prefecture.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_colors = view.findViewById(R.id.button_colors);
        button_colors.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_country_and_region = view.findViewById(R.id.button_country_and_region);
        button_country_and_region.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_dating = view.findViewById(R.id.button_dating);
        button_dating.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_directions_and_places = view.findViewById(R.id.button_directions_and_places);
        button_directions_and_places.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_drink = view.findViewById(R.id.button_drink);
        button_drink.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_eating = view.findViewById(R.id.button_eating);
        button_eating.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_emergency = view.findViewById(R.id.button_emergency);
        button_emergency.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_family = view.findViewById(R.id.button_family);
        button_family.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_feeling = view.findViewById(R.id.button_feeling);
        button_feeling.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_numbers = view.findViewById(R.id.button_numbers);
        button_numbers.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_shopping = view.findViewById(R.id.button_shopping);
        button_shopping.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_sick = view.findViewById(R.id.button_sick);
        button_sick.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_time_and_date = view.findViewById(R.id.button_time_and_date);
        button_time_and_date.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_tongue_twisters = view.findViewById(R.id.button_tongue_twisters);
        button_tongue_twisters.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_tourist_attractions = view.findViewById(R.id.button_tourist_attractions);
        button_tourist_attractions.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_transportation = view.findViewById(R.id.button_transportation);
        button_transportation.setOnClickListener(this);
        
        homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);

            }
        });
        return root;
    }
     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_greetings:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Greetings.class) ;
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_general_conversation:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), General_Conversation.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_accommodation:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Accommodation.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_celebration:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),  Celebration.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_city_and_prefecture:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), City_and_Prefecture.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_colors:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Colors.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_country_and_region:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Country_and_Region.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_dating:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Dating.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_directions_and_places:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Directions_and_Places.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_drink:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Drink.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_eating:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Eating.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_emergency:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Emergency.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_family:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Family.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_feeling:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Feeling.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_numbers:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Numbers.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_shopping:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Shopping.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_sick:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Sick.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_time_and_date:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Time_and_Date.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_tongue_twisters:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Tongue_Twisters.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_tourist_attractions:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Tourist_Attractions.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
            case R.id.button_transportation:{
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Transportation.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break; }
        }
    }

}
```

enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

You should not define the same variable in the same scope more than once.. Here the intent `i` is defined in every switch case

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        Intent i; // Define once

        case R.id.button_greetings:{
            i = new Intent(getActivity(), Greetings.class) ;
            startActivity(i);
            break; }

        case R.id.button_general_conversation:{
            i = new Intent(getActivity(), General_Conversation.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break; }

        case R.id.button_accommodation:{
            i = new Intent(getActivity(), Accommodation.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break; }

       // repeat the same for the rest of cases
```

Comment: I've tried and it says "statement must be prepended with case label".

Comment: It's ok now. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you inflate two different views from one layout? First time you set inflated view to a global field, and second time you inflate new object and return it as a result of onCreateView(). It seems like your buttons getted from view which never be shown on the screen and never will been clicked. Try to remove second inflating and use just result of first one.
And, of course, bring out your intent declaration out of switch block (before).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I can fix it now.

Comment: If it helps to fix your problem, could you mark my answer?